# Why are files missing in the first Docker exec but available in the second?

Tags: linux, filesystems, docker, alpine-linux

This is a very weird situation. We run an alpine-based docker container on Travis CI. Then we run `ls` as follows:

```
docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME ls -la specific/directory
docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME ls -la specific/directory
```

The first command shows a list of files but missing some files which should be there (part of the built image and does exist inside the image when investigated on other platforms).

Example output: Please notice the number in `file_#`

```
total 108
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         2069 Oct 21 06:08 2018_01_10_101010_file_1_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1586 Oct 21 06:08 2018_01_12_101010_file_3_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1649 Oct 21 06:08 2018_01_13_101010_file_4_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1490 Oct 21 06:08 2018_01_14_101010_file_5_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          946 Oct 21 06:08 2018_01_15_101010_file_6_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         2379 Oct 21 06:08 2018_01_16_101010_file_7_here.php
```

The second command shows a full list of files as expected.

```
total 192
drwxrwxr-x    1 nginx    nginx         4096 Oct 21 06:08 .
drwxrwxr-x    1 nginx    nginx         4096 Oct 21 06:08 ..
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         2069 Oct 21 06:08 2018_01_10_101010_file_1_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1758 Oct 21 06:08 2018_01_11_101010_file_2_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1586 Oct 21 06:08 2018_01_12_101010_file_3_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1649 Oct 21 06:08 2018_01_13_101010_file_4_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1490 Oct 21 06:08 2018_01_14_101010_file_5_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          946 Oct 21 06:08 2018_01_15_101010_file_6_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         2379 Oct 21 06:08 2018_01_16_101010_file_7_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1583 Oct 21 06:08 2018_01_17_101010_file_8_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          920 Oct 21 06:08 2018_01_18_101010_file_9_here.php
```

I also notice that the first command does not show the `.` and `..` directories.

**Why does that happen? And how to avoid it?**

BTW: It does not only happen with `ls`. When the application code tries to list the files for the first time it shows the reduced list. But listing them again shows the full list!

---

The following are more debuging commands asked by @DanilaKiver and @ClemensKaserer

Output of `docker info`:

```
Containers: 4
 Running: 4
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 30
Server Version: 18.06.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: d64c661f1d51c48782c9cec8fda7604785f93587
runc version: 69663f0bd4b60df09991c08812a60108003fa340
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.15.0-1028-gcp
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7.298GiB
Name: travis-job-8895eb3f-fd49-4241-af47-47daddf7beb5
ID: AVP5:DERI:ZI6V:ZTOR:KAAL:SPUS:ZQHT:NOOK:6IFE:VCFZ:CHL4:3QAK
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Registry Mirrors:
 https://mirror.gcr.io/
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Running the following:

```
dmesg | grep ovl
docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME sync & ls -la specific/directory
docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME ls -la specific/directory
docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME ls -la specific/directory
dmesg | grep ovl
docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME dmesg | grep ovl
```

Gives:

```
# dmesg | grep ovl
[  178.665709] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 8854 at /build/linux-gcp-yd4gNt/linux-gcp-4.15.0/fs/overlayfs/readdir.c:417 ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
[  178.665761] RIP: 0010:ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
[  178.730507] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 9214 at /build/linux-gcp-yd4gNt/linux-gcp-4.15.0/fs/overlayfs/readdir.c:417 ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
[  178.730554] RIP: 0010:ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
[  178.777656] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 9214 at /build/linux-gcp-yd4gNt/linux-gcp-4.15.0/fs/overlayfs/readdir.c:417 ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
[  178.777707] RIP: 0010:ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]

# docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME sync & ls -la specific/directory
total 184
drwxrwxr-x 2 travis travis 4096 Oct 21 11:38 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 travis travis 4096 Oct 21 11:38 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1156 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_01_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1758 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_02_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1598 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_03_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1661 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_04_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1502 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_05_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis  958 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_06_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 2391 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_07_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1583 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_08_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis  932 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_09_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1947 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_10_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1484 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_11_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1026 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_12_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 2170 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_13_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1683 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_14_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis  999 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_15_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1477 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_16_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1687 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_17_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1619 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_18_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1954 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_19_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1203 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_20_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1024 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_21_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1290 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_22_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1675 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_23_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1411 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_24_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1566 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_25_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis  958 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_26_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1122 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_27_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1131 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_28_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 3034 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_29_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1866 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_30_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 2068 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_31_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis  991 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_32_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis  995 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_33_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis  933 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_34_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 2238 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_35_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis  943 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_36_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1765 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_37_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 2895 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_38_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1501 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_39_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1444 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_40_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1722 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_41_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis 1404 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_42_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis  941 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_43_here.php
-rw-rw-r-- 1 travis travis  919 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_44_here.php

# docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME ls -la specific/directory
total 140
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1758 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_02_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1598 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_03_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1661 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_04_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1502 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_05_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          958 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_06_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         2391 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_07_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1583 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_08_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1484 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_11_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1026 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_12_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         2170 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_13_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1683 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_14_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1477 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_16_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1687 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_17_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1954 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_19_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1203 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_20_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1024 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_21_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1290 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_22_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1675 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_23_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1411 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_24_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1566 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_25_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          958 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_26_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1122 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_27_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1131 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_28_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         2068 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_31_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          991 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_32_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          995 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_33_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          933 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_34_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         2238 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_35_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          943 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_36_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         2895 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_38_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1501 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_39_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1444 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_40_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1722 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_41_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1404 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_42_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          941 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_43_here.php

# docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME ls -la specific/directory
total 192
drwxrwxr-x    1 nginx    nginx         4096 Oct 21 11:38 .
drwxrwxr-x    1 nginx    nginx         4096 Oct 21 11:38 ..
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1156 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_01_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1758 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_02_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1598 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_03_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1661 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_04_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1502 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_05_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          958 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_06_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         2391 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_07_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1583 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_08_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          932 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_09_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1947 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_10_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1484 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_11_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1026 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_12_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         2170 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_13_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1683 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_14_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          999 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_15_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1477 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_16_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1687 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_17_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1619 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_18_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1954 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_19_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1203 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_20_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1024 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_21_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1290 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_22_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1675 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_23_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1411 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_24_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1566 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_25_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          958 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_26_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1122 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_27_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1131 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_28_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         3034 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_29_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1866 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_30_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         2068 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_31_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          991 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_32_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          995 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_33_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          933 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_34_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         2238 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_35_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          943 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_36_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1765 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_37_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         2895 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_38_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1501 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_39_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1444 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_40_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1722 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_41_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx         1404 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_42_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          941 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_43_here.php
-rw-rw-r--    1 nginx    nginx          919 Oct 21 11:38 2018_04_18_000001_file_44_here.php

# dmesg | grep ovl
[  178.665709] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 8854 at /build/linux-gcp-yd4gNt/linux-gcp-4.15.0/fs/overlayfs/readdir.c:417 ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
[  178.665761] RIP: 0010:ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
[  178.730507] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 9214 at /build/linux-gcp-yd4gNt/linux-gcp-4.15.0/fs/overlayfs/readdir.c:417 ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
[  178.730554] RIP: 0010:ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
[  178.777656] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 9214 at /build/linux-gcp-yd4gNt/linux-gcp-4.15.0/fs/overlayfs/readdir.c:417 ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
[  178.777707] RIP: 0010:ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
[  213.441060] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 9378 at /build/linux-gcp-yd4gNt/linux-gcp-4.15.0/fs/overlayfs/readdir.c:417 ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
[  213.441107] RIP: 0010:ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]

# docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME dmesg | grep ovl
[  178.665709] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 8854 at /build/linux-gcp-yd4gNt/linux-gcp-4.15.0/fs/overlayfs/readdir.c:417 ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
[  178.665761] RIP: 0010:ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
[  178.730507] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 9214 at /build/linux-gcp-yd4gNt/linux-gcp-4.15.0/fs/overlayfs/readdir.c:417 ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
[  178.730554] RIP: 0010:ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
[  178.777656] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 9214 at /build/linux-gcp-yd4gNt/linux-gcp-4.15.0/fs/overlayfs/readdir.c:417 ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
[  178.777707] RIP: 0010:ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
[  213.441060] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 9378 at /build/linux-gcp-yd4gNt/linux-gcp-4.15.0/fs/overlayfs/readdir.c:417 ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
[  213.441107] RIP: 0010:ovl_iterate+0x25d/0x270 [overlay]
```

**Updated:**

This problem happens on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 but it does not happen on Ubuntu Bionic 18.04. So, it seems to be a bug in the kernel and got solved in later versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happens on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 but it does not happen on Ubuntu Bionic 18.04. So, it seems to be a bug in the kernel and got solved in later versions.

@DanilaKiver also referred to [this fix commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/67810693077afc1ebf9e1646af300436cb8103c2) which could be related to the same issue.